# Generic interface for multiple sub types of an abstract class and dynamic casting

Tags: java, oop, generics

I have a scenario that can be simplified like the following:

- I have a abstract class called **AbstractField**
- There can be many classes that extend from this class : **CurrencyField**, **DecimalField**, etc.
- Now I have a generic interface **FieldDBStore** to create or update the field details in database.
- I want to implement the above interface for each type of field (whenever it is stored differently).

Here is some code sample:

For AbstractField

```
/* AbstractField */
public abstract class AbstractField {
    //private members
    // builder
}
```

For CurrencyField

```
public class CurrencyField extends AbstractField {
    //private members
    // builder that is extended from parent class's builder
}
```

For FieldDBStore

```
interface FieldDBStore<T extends AbstractField> {
    
    void createField(T field, String tableName, String columnName);
    
    void updateField(T field);
}
```

CurrencyFieldDBStore

```
public class CurrencyFieldDBStore implements FieldDBStore<CurrencyField> {
    @Override
    public void createField(CurrencyField field, String tableName, String columnName) {
        // Some operations
        
    }

    @Override
    public void updateField(CurrencyField field) {
        // Some operations
        
    }
}
```

Now the problem: Whenever the client tries to send a field to be created/updated, it won't be knowing the field type. So, it will be sending the field as super type (AbstractField). This is resulting in the following error that is visible in eclipse

```
public AbstractField createAbstractField(AbstractField field, Long userId) { 
    //FieldType is an enum that can return appropriate DBStore implementation as per the field type
    FieldType type = field.getFieldType();
    String tableName = "SomeTableName";
    String columnName = "SomeColumnName";
    type.getFieldDBStore().createField(field, tableName, columnName);
```

In the above code, last line throws this error

> The method createField(capture#2-of ? extends AbstractField, String, String) in the type FieldDBStore<capture#2-of ? extends AbstractField> is not applicable for the arguments (AbstractField, String, String)

I tried implementing an abstract field db store and then extending it, but it is not solving the issue. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated

Comment: `type.getFieldDBStore().createField` tries to invoke a method with a specific type. For example `CurrencyField` but a `AbstractField` is not a `CurrencyField`. That would be kontravariant. Therefore you need to use an upper bound in this case. For example `void <T extends AbstractField> void createAbstractField(T field, Long userId) { }` Saying except every type which is a sub type of AbstractField

Comment: @DanielWosch Thank you! Changing the caller method as you said got the issue resolved.

Comment: You are welcome. Posted my comment as answer so you can mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`type.getFieldDBStore().createField()` tries to invoke a method with a specific type. For example `CurrencyField` but an `AbstractField` is **not** an `CurrencyField`.

That should be contravariant.

Therefore you need to use an upper bound in this case. For example

`void <T extends AbstractField> void createAbstractField(T field, Long userId) { //impl... }`

Saying: This methods excepts every type which is a sub type of `AbstractField` including `AbstractField`